# Is having default event initializer considered a good practice?

Tags: c#, .net, events

One thing that I find slightly annoying is having to null-check events. An event that has no subscribers is going to be `null`, so often times code like this has to be written:

```
MyEvent?.Invoke()
```

One solution for this problem I've found was this initialization pattern, where we initialize event with a no-op delegate:

```
public event Action MyEvent = delegate { };
```

Now, since this event is always going to have at least one dummy subscriber, we no longer have to check for `null`:

```
MyEvent.Invoke()
```

While this is pretty convenient, I was wondering whether this pattern a good practice, or is there some reason that I don't see that would make this a bad decision (aside from having to call an extra dummy subscriber, but I am fine with that)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, if firing event does not generates a large *overhead* (that's seems to be your case). In general case `MyHugeEventArgs e = new MyHugeEventArgs(...); MyHugeEvent.Invoke(this, e);` can slow down the execution.

Comment: Side note: `public event EventHandler MyEvent` is typical way to declare an event without arguments (`public event EventHandler<MyNextEventArgs> MyNextEvent` is for typical event with arguments)

Comment: Why would you do that to save yourself having to type a `?`? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thank you for the answer. I understand the convention, but what if I don't care at all about the sender, why not use `Action`?

Comment: I can't see much use in this default-implementation.  Of course you have to do *some* check, but if you do this checking for null, or by initializing the event yourself - what's the difference? Seems to be pretty opinion-based, IMHO :D Good question, but don't know if you get an satisfactory answer.

Comment: @user18387401 You're right, it is not a problem to type `?`, it is just a matter of preference I guess. I was just wondering if other people use this pattern.

Comment: @FICHEKK: nothing wrong with `Action` instead of `EventHandler`, but sticking to common practice / standard / recommended way makes your code *more readable*. It'll be easier for you and may be for other people to read, debug, maintain your code: *the least amazement* principle in action.

Comment: Just add a helper method like `RaiseMyEvent()` which will check for the null event